# I see different coloured and textured images in two opened veiwports in blender

Tags: texturing

I saved my work, but when re opened the blender file, my object was showing grey colors. I actually opened two veiwports beforehand, but one of them is showing a grey object while other one is showing the original coloured object. How do I rectify this, bring the original coloured object in both the viewports? I started learning blender a few days ago.

[image: image for reference]

Comment: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.80/editors/3dview/controls/shading.html

Comment: It would be nice to have a screenshot with the whole screen, because now there is a lot of possible relevant information missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you didnt go back in to **Material Preview**/ **Rendered** mode. After you close and reopen the file it automatically resets the viewport to solid.

[image: Viewportshading]